# IQueryable <int> does not contains definition for Contains

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm having the issue to linq to sql my sql query is

```
  Select emp_name from employee where emp_manager_id in (Select emp_id  from employee where dept_id in 
                                                    (Select dept_id from department where dept_name='admin')
                                               )
                                               and emp_salary between
                                               (Select min_salary from salarygrades where grade='B')
                                               and 
                                               (Select max_Salary from salarygrades where grade='B')
```

I'm trying to  convert this into linq expression then i go problem

```
var min_salary = from salarygrade in dbe.salarygrades where salarygrade.grade == "B" select salarygrade.min_Salary;
            var max_salary = from salarygrade in dbe.salarygrades where salarygrade.grade == "B" select salarygrade.max_Salary;
            var dept_id = from department in dbe.departments where department.dept_name.Contains("admin") select department.dept_id;
            var manager_id = from employee in dbe.employees where dept_id.Contains(employee.dept_id) select new { employee.emp_manager_id, employee.emp_id, employee.dept_id };


 var manager_id = from employee in dbe.employees where dept_id.Contains(employee.dept_id) select new { employee.emp_manager_id, employee.emp_id, employee.dept_id };
```

I'm getting `IQueryable<int>` does not contain definition for Contains methods

Comment: add `using System.Linq;` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add 
`using System.Linq` at your import statements

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.contains?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: if i replace last with                                                                                                
     var manager_id = from employee in dbe.employees where dept_id.Contains(employee.dept_id.Value) select new { employee.emp_manager_id, employee.emp_id, employee.dept_id };                  
                    my problem got solved by replaceing the line

Comment: i have no medel available